# Mkdir from OSX app

Tags: c++, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I am new to OSX development and i need your help please.

I am trying to make folder on /private/var/tmp using mkdir from my OSX app written in c++. I am using XCode 3.2.6 on OSX 10.6. The command works well. The folder is created in the path /private/var/tmp.

That's what i've done in the application : `mkdir(my_path, 0777);`

But i have a problem in the permissions of the folder. The user can modify the folder (make another folder inside, etc..) but not "everyone" or "wheel".

[image]

Translation :

- Moi -> Me
- Lecture et écriture -> Read and Write
- Lecture seulement -> Read only

I have try to make folder from terminal, i type mkdir -m 777 /private/var/tmp/**test** and the folder **test** has the good permissions :

[image]

Translation :

- Moi -> Me
- Lecture et écriture -> Read and Write

My question is, how can i do to make write permissions on the folder and from my OSX app.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that directory didn't exist earlier and those are rights that have been already set?

Comment: Thank you for your answer..I delete the folder before making tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [SUIS](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html)

> The mkdir() function shall create a new directory with name path. The file permission bits of the new directory shall be initialized from mode. **These file permission bits of the mode argument shall be modified by the process' file creation mask.**

The reason is default [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) defined for your system.

So you just need to update [umask](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/umask.html) from your process before calling mkdir or call [chown](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/chown.html) to update attributes for created folder.